# Lots of combo-boxes with key-value pairs

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, excel-2013

In sheet2 I have data key-value. For example:

```
1 Thomas
2 Michael
```

In sheet1 I would have combo-box with items (keys). And if I choose from combo-box for example key `1` then next to combo-box (in cell) I would see value `Thomas`. It is quite easy with VBA, but I need a lot of such combo-boxes. So if I use VBA then for every combo-box I have to copy the same code of VBA.

Can we do it without VBA? Can we use any formulas? Do you have any idea? If not, how can I make one of code in VBA to all combo-boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at Data Validation for your combo boxes for keys and VLOOKUP for values. No VBA needed.

Comment: Could you give me more information about Data Validiation? I have never used it. I know what is VLOOKUP formula, but I don't know how can I use Data Validation in my combo-boxes.

Comment: From the Excel toolbar, Data -> Data Validation -> List (Allow). You can then pick the "Source". Excel will make you cell as a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use VBA, i would recommend something like this:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
     getName(ComboBox1.Value, "A3")
End Sub

Sub ComboBox2_Change()
     getName(ComboBox2.Value, "A7")
End Sub

Sub getName(key as Integer, destCell as String)
    Sheet1.Range(destCell).Value = Sheet2.Cells(key, 2).Value
End sub
```

There is a more complicated solution using WithEvents...

I would go with the idea of @Robert Co